# Middleman processing README file into a directory

Tags: github, static, middleman

I'm having trouble setting up a readme file for my Middleman static website. I've added both a README and a CNAME file for when the static content is deployed to Github. The CNAME file is copied across properly, but the README file is being processed into /readme/index.html.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore certain files using this in your `config.rb`

```
page "/README", :directory_index => false
```

[It's documented on the Middleman website](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/pretty-urls/#toc_2)